# How do you prove $A$ is diagonalizable and $\lambda \ge 0$ for each eigenvalue of $A$ $\implies$ $A=B^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How would you show that $A=B^2$ if $A$ is diagonalizable and $\lambda \ge 0$ for each eigenvalue of $A$?

Could anyone give a direction to start the problem?

Comment: (1) Did you try something? (2) Do you understand what diagonalizable means? (3) Do you know what is the square root of a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries on the diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to a basis of eigenvectors, $A$ actually *is* a diagonal matrix. I assume you work over $\Bbb R$ as ground field; in that case, each $\lambda\ge 0$  is the square of a real number called $\sqrt \lambda$. Picking a square root for each diagonal entry produces a suitable linear map $B$ with $B^2=A$.

Comment: I did have thought of the $\sqrt {\lambda}$, but I am not sure how to prove that a diagonalizable matrix is a diagonal matrix. Is that because A is similar to diagonal matrix D and so A itself is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @1412: It is not true that $A$ **is** a diagonal matrix. It is a diagonal matrix when considered in a suitable basis. What you have to do (written out in matrices) is that $A = VDV^{-1}$ for a diagonal matrix $D$. All diagonal entries of $D$ are $\geq 0$, so there is a matrix $S$ with $D = S^2$. I leave it to you to conclude $A = B^2$ with $B = VSV^{-1}$.